# Display a CSV file as an HTML table on the browser using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'd like to take a CSV file living server-side and display it dynamically as an html table using PHP. E.g., this:

```
Name, Age, Sex, Email
"Hector, George", 163, M, abcd@mail.com
```

should become this:

```
<html><body><table>
<tr> <td>Name</td> <td>Age</td> <td>Sex</td> <td>Email</td></tr>
<tr> <td>Hector, George</td> <td>163</td> <td>M</td> <td>abcd@mail.com</td> </tr>
</table></body></html>
```

I made a code :

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$file = fopen("comma.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . $cell. "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($file);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

But the problem is no seperate columns are dispalyed, only a single column containing the entire row.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Edited)

So I am getting an output like this (using a different csv file) -
[image]

And the html code generated is -

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

td, th {

  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>

<html><body><table>

<table border="1"><tr><td>First_Name    Last_Name   Email   Gender</td></tr>
<tr><td>A   X   c@gghfug.com    M</td></tr>
<tr><td>B   Y   d@fghjdfg.com   F</td></tr>
<tr><td>A   X   c@gghfug.com    M</td></tr>
<tr><td>B   Y   d@fghjdfg.com   F</td></tr>
<tr><td>A   X   c@gghfug.com    M</td></tr>
<tr><td>B   Y   d@fghjdfg.com   F</td></tr>
<tr><td>A   X   c@gghfug.com    M</td></tr>

</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Using the sample data you have given, the output seems OK (`<tr><td>Hector, George</td><td> 163</td><td> M</td><td> abcd@mail.com</td></tr>`).

Comment: But its being displayed as a single column here. Can I attach an image here?

Comment: Better to show the generated HTML as it's clearer to see what is being generated.

Comment: Use the View Source feature in your browser to see what the actual output is

Comment: Maybe delimiter has a wrong value?

Comment: Your data file in the output is totally different to the one in the question.  Looks as though your real data file uses tabs as delimeters.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NigelRen. The delimiter was tab. Saved the same file in text format and made it into csv file, and that just did the trick.